# How to change shell to bash to another user?

Tags: ubuntu

I uninstalled zsh on my root user, but I forgot to change to bash before.

Now, I have access to another user that is not root. Can I change from zsh to bash in my root user?

I know that I could change the /etc/passwd to use bash instead of zsh, but this requires sudo

Comment: Have you tried `sudo bash` in your other user? That should not login, so would not invoke the shell stated in /etc/passwd.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant I can't access to the admin user because when I change to it I have the error: "/usr/bin/zsh file or directory doesn't exist". And the user I have access is not an admin user

Comment: This would involve privilege escalation, cause you need root in order to change its shell. I don't think there's any way around it. If you're not `sudo/wheel` group member such changes are impossible IIRC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the root password, you can use `su`:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c chsh
```